# How to get word break working on ie11 and edge?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, word-wrap

I have a problem with the word break under ie11 and edge, my titles should look like this :
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcl5t.png)

And it actually look like this : [actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwvHf.png)

I tried `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and `word-break: break-word`, none of which work with either of the browsers.

Is there any way to make it work with ms browsers ?

p.s. my html kinda look like this :

```
<div class="col-md">
    <h1 class="name">
        <span class="field">text i want to word break correctly</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm in favor of welcomegkm's answer. Have you tried the solution in IE and Edge to see if it can solve the problem? You can also try to add `overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;` in the CSS to make it compatible with IE, Edge and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use your CSS like this.

```
word-break: break-word; /* Chrome, Safari */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE11, Firefox */
```